# SwiftUI: How to display modal sheet on top of DetailView, not MasterView in regular mode

Tags: modal-dialog, swiftui

I have a Master->Detail app. The DetailView displays a modal sheet. This works fine on a iPhone XR in portait. But in landscape, the modal sheet does not appear on top of the DetailView, but on top of the MasterView instead.

How to prevent that?

I'm using NavigationView inside the modal sheet. If I remove it, the problem seems to go away. Except that I no longer have a title and close button, which I need.

Here's the definition of the master view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text ("Master 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text ("Master 2")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Master"))
        }
    }
}
```

Pressing a row will display the modal sheet:

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button("Detail 1") {
                self.isPresented = true
            }
            Button("Detail 2") {
                self.isPresented = true
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail"))
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            SheetView()
        })
    }
}
```

The modal sheet relies on NavigationView to have a title and close button. But as a result the modal will be displayed on top of the master view in regular (landscape).

```swift
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // Mandatory for Title and Button
            Form {
                Text("Modal 1")
                Text("Modal 2")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Some Modal"))
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Close")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your NavigationView in your SheetView, is also using the landscape size class, which means the Sheet view is hidden. In your SheetView, force it to compact, and that will solve your problem:

```swift
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
            NavigationView { // Mandatory for Title and Button
                Form {
                    Text("Modal 1")
                    Text("Modal 2")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Some Modal"))
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing: Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Text("Close")
                })
            }.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .compact)        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
NavigationView {
    ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

PS: `.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .compact)` may help but failed in my situation.